# How to pass props without creating setters and getters?

Tags: vuejs2

In the code below I pass an object to a child component. Vue creates a pair of setter/getter for each property in this object. In other words, it binds each property to make the component reactive. Is there a way to pass an object, like I'm doing here, but without binding? In a real life application I pass an object with ten's of properties and a setter/getter pair is created for each also. This impacts performance a bit. What would you recommend?

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '<div>Child!</div>',
  props: ['params'],
  created () {
    console.log(this.params)
  }
})
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
     return {params: {a: 1, b: 2}}
  } 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"><child :params="params"></child></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

I would be highly surprised if converting your properties into getters/setters, which is at the core of Vue's reactivity, is the cause of a performance issue.

The only way to pass a property would be to expose it to Vue at some point, which means that it *will* be converted to getter/setters when you expose it. In order pass the object *without* them, you would need to do something like `JSON.stringify` the object and `JSON.parse` it on the other side. Then, as soon as you try to use in in your child (by adding it as a data property for example) it's going to be converted into a reactive object again.

Comment: you're right there's no performance issue, indeed it's very fast. What I meant to say is that it would be faster (I guess, not by a lot) if there was no such conversion to setters/getters. Anyway, `JSON.stringify` is exactly what I need. Thank you, sir!